# API (How to get request to API and capture response?)

Tags: api, rest, testing, methods

How to get request to API and capture response? Please provide a simple answer. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cypress.io which can send requests to your API and catch responses.